# Simple way to convert list into dict with False values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What is the simplest way to convert some list like

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

...into a dict of following form:

```
d = {'a': False, 'b': False, 'c': False}
```

Comment: Try: `dict.fromkeys(l, False)`

Comment: The answer to "is there a way" questions is almost always "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [enke suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578556/simple-way-to-convert-list-into-dict-with-false-values/71578613#comment126507242_71578556) you can use `fromkeys` method of `dict` class to convert the list or any other iterable into a dict by a fixed value for all keys.

```py
In [1]: a = [1,2, "hello"]                                                                                                                                                      

In [2]: dict.fromkeys(a, False)                                                                                                                                                 
Out[2]: {1: False, 2: False, 'hello': False}
```

And also you can use dict comprehension as below:

```py
In [1]: a = [1,2, "hello"]                                                                                                                                                      

In [2]: {key: False for key in a}                                                                                                                                               
Out[2]: {1: False, 2: False, 'hello': False}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/fromkeys.html)

```
d = dict.fromkeys(l, False)
```

Test it [online](https://onlinegdb.com/jWKIaK1E2).

Answer (score 2):

You can use dict-comprehension, Pythonic-style:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> dct = {x: False for x in l}
>>> dct
{'a': False, 'b': False, 'c': False}
```